# When receiving a post with chunked encoding, PHP is unable to read the POST data via $_POST

Tags: php, apache, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I have two servers running on shared hosting with different providers. One is running PHP 5.2.9 in Apache 2.2.16, the other is running PHP 5.2.17.

Scripts on both servers work fine with my application unless they receive a POST with chunked encoding.

When this happens, as is sometimes the case from mobile clients, PHP seems unable to access the post data through `$_POST`. What's more, the first of the servers mentioned above, used to work fine with chunked encoding until 5/6 days ago when an update seems to have taken place (although the hosts are unwilling/unable to confirm this).

Can anyone suggest what settings in PHP or maybe Apache would affect this?

P.S. I am in ongoing and protracted discussions with the technical support from both hosts and which don't seem to be bearing fruit.

Comment: This needs a dump of an exemplary chunked encoded request so it's clear under which conditions the script fails. Also how are you simulating chunked encoded requests for testing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this question - My webhosts have advised that this appears to be a bug in apache!

Comment: I've seen others suggest that this problem only manifested itself with FastCGI, and if you turned that off, it would work fine. I can't seem to get it to work regardless of the FastCGI setting. Did you ever find an answer to your question?